# Disposing in service layer и где вызывать сохранение

Tags: .net

Есть две простые сущности, контекст бд, два репозитория и unit of work(картинка ниже), который реализовывает IDisposable

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же есть сервисы, вот один из них
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите где должен вызываться метод Dispose для экземпляра EFUnitOfWork или может нужно что-то ещё организовать или добавить, чтобы очищался контекст бд и где должно вызываться сохранение после каких либо изменений.
Гуглил особо ничего не нагуглил, везде как будто забывают про то что нужно где-то очищать контекст с Unit of Work

Comment: Вы же через DI инстанс получаете? Диспоуз в таком случае обычно на совести того же DI

Comment: В случае стандартного ServiceCollection: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines